# For GraphX how do i convert an array of object to an array of Edges

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-graphx

I have an array of object like this

```
 edges: Array[Array[(Long, Long, String)]] = Array(Array((-209215114,197853780,Investor), (-209215114,-322475625,Investor), ...
```

and i want to convert it to an array of Edge to pass to a Graph builder. Here is what i am using:

```
 val eRDD: RDD[Edge[(VertexId, VertexId, String)]] = edges.map(x => Edge(x(0), x(1), x(2)))
```

I am getting the following error:

```
<console>:107: error: type mismatch;
found   : (Long, Long, String)
required: org.apache.spark.graphx.VertexId
(which expands to)  Long
   val eRDD: RDD[Edge[(VertexId, VertexId, String)]] = edges.map(x => Edge(x(0), x(1), x(2)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your type definition is wrong. Either do:

```
val eRDD: RDD[Edge[String]] = edges.map(x => Edge(x(0), x(1), x(2)))
```

or just do:

```
val eRDD = edges.map(x => Edge(x(0), x(1), x(2)))
```

And let Scala infer the type for you.